# How to setup language change only in current window?

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout

In my Xfce in Linux Mint when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, the keyboard language changes for the whole system, not just for the currently selected window. This is very uncomfortable.

How can I set up Xfce, so that the language only changes in the currently selected window?

The layout selection dialog looks like this:

[image: XFCE keyboard layout selection]

Comment: Maybe, kbdd is what you need..
https://github.com/qnikst/kbdd

Comment: Should this the changed keyboard language be kept associated with the window upon selection of another window? What would need to happen when you have multiple terminals in one window in multiple tabs, each their own language I presume?

Answer (score 3):

The standard XFCE keyboard layout tool is basically a GUI frontend for `setxkb` and as far as I know only allows you to switch layouts globally. If you want per application/window settings try [xfce4-keyboard-plugin](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin), set "Manage layout" from "globally" to "per window" or "per application":

[image: keyboard layouts plugin]

Comment: Looks like i have a some different plugin without layout managing : http://oi57.tinypic.com/16baiwx.jpg

Comment: OK, that is part of the xfwm4 (I guess) and afaik it can't do per window/application settings (it basically is a GUI for `setxkb`. I suggest you try the plug-in mentioned. For Debian package see https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xfce4-xkb-plugin